# Эхо сервер на двух разных машинах, подключенных к одному wifi с\с++

Tags: c++, клиент-сервер, wifi

Есть две машины на Linux, подключённые к одному Wi-Fi роутеру. Нужно реализовать на них эхо-сервер на C\C++. IP у меня один на обе машины. Вопрос в следующем: как мне получить реальный адрес сервера, чтобы можно было к нему коннектиться?

Пытался гуглить в лоб типа `эхо-сервер wifi` — ничего дельного по теме не нашёл. Так что даже если вы подскажете мне правильный гугл-запрос на эту тему, буду очень рад.

Comment: а разве есть разница для сокета слать по проводу или воздуху???

Comment: `IP у меня один на обе машины.` - в смысле внешний айпи? или один айпи внутри сети?

Comment: @KoVadim Внешний.

Comment: Похоже, что Вы хотите подключатся к своему серверу из внешнего мира. Тогда Вам нужно сделать проброс портов на роутере. Это можно сделать как ручками в админке, таки всякими upnp. О том, что нужно иметь реальный внешний айпи, я думаю Вы должны знать.

Comment: @KoVadim Да, это тоже, но в дальнейшем, так скажем, обучении. В данный же момент у меня есть два лэптопа на убунте, подключенных к общему wi-fi роутеру и я хочу сделать из них пару клиент-сервер. И не могу сообразить какой ip указывать, потому что на оба устройства у меня один ip, т.к. они подключены к одному роутеру.

Comment: @Alex.B для сокета разницы никакой, если я правильно понимаю, как это работает :)

Comment: то, что у Вас внешний айпи один на двоих, ещё ничего не значит. У них есть внутренние айпи, которые должны быть уникальны в пределах локальной сети (если они одинаковые, то у Вас проблема и ее нужно исправлять немедленно). Посмотреть свой айпи можно в консоли командой ifconfig. А дальше берите любой пример клиент-сервер и вперед.

Comment: Про локальные ip был в курсе, но не знал как их узнать. Так что спасибо, вы ответили на мой вопрос :)

Comment: @KoVadim, оформите свой коммент как ответ.